# Conditionally drop an insert in a before insert trigger without returning error

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have the following function in a before insert trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.table_somefun()
RETURNS trigger AS
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.col2 NOT NULL THEN
    NEW.col1 := CASE NEW.col1
                     WHEN '121432' THEN '321123'
                     ELSE <command> END CASE; --there should be a command aborting insertion without error or exception
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

The `ELSE` statement should abort insertion. Is there a command which drops the query without telling it to the client and leaving the table untouched?

Comment: `RETURN NULL` to cancel insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
RETURN NULL;
```

instead of

```
RETURN NEW;
```

to cancel the `INSERT` for the row and do nothing instead.

But you cannot execute a PL/pgSQL statement *inside* an SQL `CASE` expression. (Don't confuse [SQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) with the similar [control structure `CASE` of PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)!)
Could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.table_somefun()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.col2 NOT NULL THEN
      IF NEW.col1 = '121432' THEN  -- could also be plpgsql CASE ...
         NEW.col1 := '321123';
      ELSE
         RETURN NULL;
      END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```